# Would it be possible to display geo-location with user's profile tile

Tags: feature-request, question-quality, profile-page

I see a lot of questions on StackOverflow, from users with reputation 1, and common profile name, like userXXXXXX. Usually it feels like the individual is asking the community to do their job, however small the task is. I pretty much started ignoring those posts, but can't help myself and wonder, where do those users come from? Could we perhaps enhance the user's tile displayed under the post, or the detailed profile, to display approximate geo-location?

Like this site does: http://freegeoip.net/

Comment: Besides obvious privacy issues, this looks like a potential source of discrimination. Are you sure the best-behaved users would come from the US? Clearly, some users write questions that are badly received due to poor English language skills. That's expected, but where they are shouldn't really influence that. (There are a number of native English speakers who also struggle to put two sentences together, by the way.)

Comment: Shouldn't the focus be on the question, not the writer, let alone the writer's location? If it is a good question, upvote it, and if you know an answer, answer it. If it is a bad question, comment to improve it and/or downvote and/or vote to close it.

Comment: I don't want to discriminate anyone. But I will die hunting people who take credit for work they have not performed. Language not withstanding, the questions are usually simple and show no effort whatsoever to attempt a resolution on the individual's own part. Is it possible that we have so many beginners? Sure, and I will die helping them out. Yet, my curiosity, if there is a systemic abuse coming from the same set of IP pools, can't be satisfied. Having ran Cognoise.com for few years, I have first hand experience of such abuse. But I do understand your concerns.

Answer (score 3):

> Would it be possible to display geo-location with user's profile tile

Yes. It would be possible. But would it be **etchical** to reveal one's anonymity?

> where do those users come from?

They come from all corners of the world.

> it feels like the individual is asking the community to do their job, however small the task is.

There will always be leeches, they exists in every country you can name.

I'm from Iceland (honestly, it doesn't matter where I'm from), some people don't even know that my country exists, but I want answers to my questions like anyone else. Do I deserve those answers less than someone from Germany, USA, Poland or Nigeria? Or does any of them deserve it less?

I get your point, but acting differently towards users depending on their source is nothing more than discrimination and it would be a big step backwards. It's bad enough to be treated differently out on the streets, let's give people the advantage of being anonymous on the internet, at least.

One's expertise in English is individual-based, you can find experts in English in all countries of the world, at the same time you can find an adult native English-speakers who couldn't beat a teenager in a foreign country in English grammar.

Can we do it? Yes. Should we do it? **No**, but if we would do it it should be optional for each user.

Having a spam-blocker for the exact same ip-addresses is something entirely else but that's something that should be (and probably is) built within the system itself, there should not be anything displayed for us to see or identify.

Comment: Never been to Iceland, but I hear is quite beautiful. I have been, and will continue helping others regardless of their cultural or physical origins. But I hate "leechers" who feed on others' hard work and dedication to enhance their skills.

Comment: I understand, but I fear that knowing everyone's location will push you away from good questions and good users just because they came from the same country as another user who turned out to be a leech.

Comment: Again, country nor individual IP address is not what interests me. Perhaps I should have worded my question differently. I am more intrigued, if all those userXXXXXX account are coming from the exact same IP pool. Keep in mind, that an external facing IP pool belongs to one owner. It would be interesting to know, what is the average quality score coming from that pool.